# To get/copy the web-address typed into an address bar of any browser

Tags: java, browser

Please, I need my running java application to be able to detect a web address that is typed into any browser's address bar. This is because I need it to make a decision depending on which website is typed into the bar. It would be best if I can rather get this url through other means aside the address bar - like from the memory. Is this possible with java?  It does not have to be through address bar only - any simple means is OK.
I need listen to which web address is about to be visited so my java application runs a method once the address is entered. My java application/program method goes "true" if the url to be visited matches the urls I have listed. Your kind help to go about this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you making a program which listens to what a user types into their web browser? They may be a simpler way to achieve what you want but we need more details.

Comment: Exactly, I need listen to which web address is about to be visited so  my java application runs a method once the address is entered. My java application/program method goes "true" if the url to be visited matches the urls I have listed.

Comment: Say, if I visit, amazon.com, my application automatically starts a method that runs Calcultor, so I don't have to go and click calculator. If I visit a page with pdf to read, it detects the pdf and launches dictionary.... What's dodgy about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't directly access the address bar of any web browser using java. Some techniques that I can think of to accomplish this:

1. Use JNI(Java Native Interface) and use `GetAsyncKeyState` of C++ to get the key pressed. In this manner you would loose the platform independent nature of java and would have to write C++ code also.
2. Write a simple proxy server in Java and link your browsers to it so that every request the browser makes goes to your program which in turn get's the webpages. In this manner you would  be able to log the URL's requested by the browser.